# Dynamic redirect from one domain to another

Tags: php, redirect

I need to do one project, that users can dynamically redirect from "redirecting" domain to our real domain.

For example:
from - www.nicedomain.com/shampoo
to - www.notsonicedomain.com/product/shampoo-head-and-shoulders-2225.html

Problem is I need to allow the users to add, change and remove the rules.
So I thought about storing the rules in database, creating front end where they can add/change/remove the rules (that's not a problem at all so far), but how to actually do the redirects?

Friend of mine suggested that we should set the server so all traffic from www.nicedomain.com is redirected to index.php and then somehow read what the entered url was and redirect according to it.

Any ideas how to do that? Or better solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a pattern in the old URL that allows you to translate it to now - and from your example I gather there is not - you will need an intermediary script like suggested by your friend to apply whatever logic is used to determine where the request should be redirected to.

The script would then terminate in something like this:

```
header('Location: ' . $new_url, true, 301);
exit;
```

This would be safer than dynamically building the htaccess anyway as they break the site on the slightest error while within the PHP script you can catch exceptions and provide adequate fallbacks.